# How do you pause a looped animation in SVG.js?

Tags: animation, svg, svg.js

I’ve got a looped animation that looks like this:

```
foreground.animate(1000, '>').stroke({ opacity: 0, width: 34 }).loop();
```

I want to incorporate a delay of 800ms into each loop. Specifically before each time the stroke animates to `{ opacity: 0, width: 34 }`. I’ve tried adding a delay in the animation:

```
foreground.animate(1000, '>', 800).stroke({ opacity: 0, width: 34 }).loop();
```

… but that just delays the first loop. Then I tried adding `delay()`:

```
foreground.animate(1000, '>').stroke({ opacity: 0, width: 34 }).delay(800).loop();
```

… but that, too, only adds the delay once.

Is it possible to have each loop include an 800ms delay at the beginning of each loop?

Comment: I've figured out solutions for other SVG.js animations using `setInterval` and also, like [this example](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/498), using `.after()` for recursion. But when I apply the solution to your animation, one that animates stroke, it only fires once. So I'm thinking it has to do specifically with animating attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one way you could achieve this is by placing the animation related code in a function, and calling that function on the end of each animation:

```
function cycle() {
  this.stroke({width: 0, opacity: 1}) 
      .animate(1000, '>', 800)
      .stroke({opacity:0, width: 34})
      .after(cycle);
}
```

Then we can use `cycle.apply(foreground)` to get `this` to be the element(s) being transformed and the animation started:

```js
var draw = SVG('content').size(500, 300)
var circle = draw.circle(100).attr({ fill: 'steelblue' }).move(200,20)

cycle.apply(circle);

function cycle() {
  this.stroke({width: 0, opacity: 1})
      .animate(1000, '>', 800)
      .stroke({opacity:0, width: 34})
      .after(cycle);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: For svg.js v2 this is the correct solution. In v3 there will be easier ways to achieve that